# How to choose related objects while using performing data import using data loader?

Tags: data-loader, externalid

I want to migrate data of account and opportunity from org1 to org2.

To do this I have created external id field on org 2. And Pupated it with Id field from org 1. When i map AccountID field of opportunity to external id field it shoes error. **insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 0019000001AY1iP**

I am following this document https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002783

But not able to see option to Choose your related objects (Step 6)

Did I miss anything ? or its just new version of data loader?

Answer (score 1):

Well my bad. I was not selection option "Upsert" instead I was selecting "insert"

This only works for Upsert operation in data loader.

Interestingly you can use external id for insert operation in apex but not data loader.

PS: posting this answer with hope that it may help someone on bad day with sleep depreciated state like me.